# How to change the css of popupwindow in mapbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I am practising my rails skills by creating a sort of airbnb page for a fake product. Now I have created cards on the first half of the screen and the other half is covered by mapbox. Everything is working fine, when I hover over the card a popup will show below the marker on the map. The question is how can I change the css or styling of the popup window? Now it's just a white square with tekst in it.

thank you

Comment: 1. Inspect the element in the web inspector. 2. Write CSS that targets element. 3. Get more coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [`Popup` element](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup) exposed by the Mapbox GL JS API, you could check [the popup's source code](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/84690ba86159e9dd80f22e82594915138fe1dfe6/src/ui/popup.js#L84-L480) to identify the names of the relevant classes for each component of the HTML element and modify or add to them in your application's CSS. The better option is probably to use the [`Popup#addClassName` method](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup#addclassname) provided by the GL JS API, which allows you to add a custom class to the popup container element (hence changing the element's styling while respecting abstraction).